# The value of attribute "if" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: zk, zul

I'm double condition to do a test on my progressmeter. This the fist condition that I use:

```
<zk if="${item.progres <= '33'}">
  <style> span.z-progressmeter-image{ background-image:url('images/vert.GIF'); } </style>
</zk>
```

When I run the program I have this error:

> The value of attribute "if" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: Check that it is not `null` first.

Comment: <zk if="${item.progres <= '33'}">
          <style>
           span.z-progressmeter-image{
           background-image:url('images/vert.GIF');
           }
          </style>
         </zk>

Comment: you are right in the first my progress is null

Comment: but my program java works when i use  progressmeter by default , now i need to change color of my progress bar using condition if

Comment: Is that EL? Is ZK using a XML based view technology? If so, use `le` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Thank you it works :D  i thought that i can use <= ; by the way i use this url to find more operators "http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/EL_Expressions/Operators"